# Salvar dados no cliente para posterior uso

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, webforms

Tenho uma aplicação web form em que o usuário entra com alguns valores para efetuar uma análise. São dois valores item e quantidade, estes dados ficam em um `List<>` que é usado como `DataSource` de um `GridView`. Podem ter até 50 itens, mas normalmente não ultrapassa 5 itens.

Uso os seguinte código para manipular os valore digitados:

```
public class Analise
{
    public int Item { get; set; }
    public int Quantidade { get; set; }
    public double CustoUnitario { get; set; }
    public double CustoAnual { get; set; }
}

static List<Analise> analiseLista = new List<Analise>();


protected void btnAdicionar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        lblErro.Text = "";
        //Regex para validar somente números
        Regex soNumeros = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+$");
        if (!soNumeros.IsMatch(txtItem.Text) || !soNumeros.IsMatch(txtQuantidade.Text))
        {
            lblErro.Text = "Valore devem ser numéricos";
            return;
        }

        Int32 item = Convert.ToInt32(txtitem.Text);
        Int32 quantidade = Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantidade.Text);

        using (BDEntities db = new BDEntities())
        {
            //Verifica ser item existe em TB_item 
            var itemBD = (from c in db.TB_item
                                where c.item == item
                                select new
                                {
                                    c.CUSTO_item
                                }).ToList();
            if (itemBD.Count == 0)
            {
                //Se não existir mensagem de erro
                lblErro.Text = "item: " + item + " não cadastrada!";
            }
            else
            {
                //Se existir continua o processo
                custoUnitarioitem = (Double)itemBD.FirstOrDefault().CUSTO_item;
                custoAnual = (quantidade * custoUnitarioitem);

                //Verifica se item existe na lista analiseLista
                var existeAnalise = analiseLista.Where(c => c.item.Equals(item)).FirstOrDefault();
                if (existeAnalise == null)
                {
                    //Se não existir INCLUI
                    var novo = new Analise() { item = item, Quantidade = quantidade, CustoUnitarioitem = custoUnitarioitem, CustoAnual = custoAnual };
                    analiseLista.Add(novo);
                }
                else
                {
                    //Se existir ALTERA ou EXLCUI
                    if (quantidade == 0)
                    {
                        //Se quantidade zero exclui item da analiseLista
                        analiseLista.Remove(existeAnalise);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Se quantidade maior que zero e capcacidade existe em analiseLista ALTERA 
                        existeAnalise.item = item;
                        existeAnalise.Quantidade = quantidade;
                        existeAnalise.CustoUnitarioitem = custoUnitarioitem;
                        existeAnalise.CustoAnual = custoAnual;
                    }
                }
                //Atualiza o grid com os valores
                gdvAnalise.DataSource = analiseLista.OrderBy(a => a.item).ToList();
                gdvAnalise.DataBind();
                double somatorio = analiseLista.Sum(x => Convert.ToDouble(x.CustoAnual));
                txtTotal.Text = somatorio.ToString();
            }
        }
        txtitem.Text = null;
        txtQuantidade.Text = null;
        txtitem.Focus();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;

    }
}
```

Fica assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Preciso salvar o conteúdo deste `List` para que sempre que o usuário entrar na aplicação eles estejam disponíveis e sejam carregados em um `GridView` com a útilma análise efetuada. Não queria cira uma tabela no bd para isto.

Como poderia efetuar este procedimento usar Cache ou existe outra opção?

Ou terei de criar uma tabela no BD para isto

Comment: Você quer saber três coisas diferentes não relacionadas então deveria ser três perguntas. Mas procure elaborar mais a pergunta, dar algum contexto.

Comment: Vou tentar elaborar melhor a pergunta.

Comment: Não sei o que você está pretendendo fazer mas essas três coisa não tem nenhuma relação. Não dá para escolher entre as três para resolver o que você quer. Provavelmente só cache está relacionado com o problema. Claro, eu posso ter entendido errado, mas aí precisa esclarecer mais porque você está pensando nessas três possibilidades. O que você entende que elas ajudarão.

Comment: Então estou misturando as coisas. Vou editar. Mas a ideia é salvar um list com alguns dados e quando o usuário logar carregar um `gridview` com ele.

Comment: Acho que o mais fácil é utilizar `BinarySerialization` para um arquivo. No carregamento do programa você lê este arquivo e de-serializa os dados.

Comment: Será que agora esta mais claro?

Comment: @Vinícius Gobbo A. de Oliveira Ao usar `BinarySerialization` onde os dados ficam gravados?

Comment: O mais comum é gravá-lo em um arquivo qualquer. A maior vantagem dele é além da velocidade de gravação e leitura, é que ele suporta a gravação de árvores complexas de objetos. E é muito fácil usar.

Comment: @Vinícius Gobbo A. de Oliveira Acho que me expressei mal. Fica na máquina do cliente? Vi um exemplo e me pareceu simples. http://www.centerspace.net/examples/nmath/csharp/core/binary-serialization-example.php

Comment: Sim, desde que sua aplicação não seja ASP.Net. Se ela for C#, usando WPF ou WinForms, por exemplo, o arquivo pode ficar sim do lado do cliente. Se sua aplicação for ASP.Net, você não conseguirá gravar arquivos no cliente, porque não há suporte a isso.

Comment: Toda vez que eu vejo um `catch (Exception ex) throw ex;` eu tenho vontade de chorar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Claro que há outras opções mas pode ser que usar uma tabela no banco seja realmente a melhor.

Pense nesse cenário: o usuário abre a página no computador do trabalho, cria a tal análise, depois de um tempo volta a essa página e a última análise aparece automaticamente pois estava salva no cliente (browser.) Aí esse usuário resolve usar outro browser ou até mesmo outro computador e nada é lembrado. Isso seria intuitivo para o usuário? É o que você realmente quer implementar?

Se você achar que o cenário acima não é problema, então você pode buscar alternativas de armazenamento local (no cliente) como `window.localStorage`, `window.indexedDB` ou a `File API`. Todas essas alternativas podem não funcionar em todos os tipos de browser.

Outras alternativas que envolvem o armazenamento no servidor são equivalentes ao uso de um banco de dados e, pior, podem padecer de limitações como não funcionar corretamente quando você tem mais de um servidor web (web farms). Eu sugeriria reconsiderar e usar o banco de dados ao invés de criar algo mais frágil.

Comment: Muito obrigado pelas sugestões vou pesquisar. O cenário descrito não seria um problema, são poucos usuários em uma intranet cada um com seu micro e browser é único. Existe um bd com os dados e ciar a tabela gera uma burocracia, então fiz esta página que usa os dados do bd e quebra um galho. Então me pediram se dava para salvar. Se der trabalho não farei. É uma gambiarra, mas que ajuda muito ao usuário, então a precariedade é compensada.